# How to redirect, in postfix, outgoing mails that get blocked, to another email address?

Tags: configuration, postfix, forwarding

I'm a happy user of a postfix mail server. But, every now and than an outgoing mail is blocked by the receiving system.  Be it that that system considers the mail as spam, or for some other reason.

I would like such outgoing, but blocked (or otherwise failing) mails to be redirected to another mail address.

Thanks in advance for any hint how to configure this.

Comment: If you configure DMARC you can provide a mail adress which will get forensic reports (for DKIM failures, at least).